# AWS Cognito - how to determine if unauthenticated user?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have AWS Lambda functions working fine with Cognito authenticated users.

I am now trying to get unauthenticated Cognito users going.

I cannot find any way at the back end to determine if the current user that called the Lambda function is authenticated or unauthenticated.

The identifying information that I have about the user is their Cognito IdentityId but how can I use that to find out of unauthenticated?

I'm using Python boto3.6 in Lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this `http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.describe_identity`

you get the logins if it is a auth user. never used it, but I think that is the way to know

EDIT:
From OP: yes this is correct - the important thing is that the absence of the key "Logins" in the returned value means that the user is unauthenticated.

```
res = client2.describe_identity(
    IdentityId=context.identity.cognito_identity_id
)
if ('Logins' not in res.keys()):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you yes this is correct - the important thing is that the absence of the key "Logins" in the returned value means that the user is unauthenticated.